# Adding browserstack functionality to beginner behat web test tutorial

Tags: behat, browserstack

As a behat (and browserstack) beginner, I have followed the beginner behat web feature [tutorial](http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/cookbook/behat_and_mink.html).  I had one issue, that was solved by adding "fabpot/goutte": "1.*@stable" to the mix as recommended in a stackoverflow post. Now with a working tutorial, I would like to get this to run on browserstack. However the various guides I have followed, have all resulted in various and different errors when modifying my behat.yml. (I was able to get a [git example](https://github.com/browserstack/behat-mink-browserstack) working, but unable to adapt my tutorial example to work). Here are my behat files at present.

```
composer.json:
{
    "require": {
        "behat/behat": "~2.5",
        "behat/mink-extension": "~1.3",
        "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "~1.2",
        "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "~1.2",
        "fabpot/goutte": "1.*@stable"
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin/"
    }
}


behat.yml:
default:
    extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
            base_url:
            goutte: ~
            selenium2: ~




testscenario.feature:
Feature: ...

@javascipt
scenario: ...
steps...



FeatureContext.php
<?php

use Behat\Behat\Context\ClosuredContextInterface,
    Behat\Behat\Context\TranslatedContextInterface,
    Behat\Behat\Context\BehatContext,
    Behat\Behat\Exception\PendingException;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\PyStringNode,
    Behat\Gherkin\Node\TableNode;

use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext;

class FeatureContext extends MinkContext
{...working functions...}
```

Now here's an example of a git behat.yml that works (for me) with the out of the box git repo:

```
default:
    extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            sessions:
                my_session:                
                    browser_stack: 
                        username: "username"
                        access_key: "accesskey"
                        capabilities: {"browser" :"Chrome", "os": "OS X", "os_version": "Yosemite", "browserstack-debug": true}
```

But if I try to use the git behat.yml in my project I get the error:

```
PHP Warning:  require(Behat\MinkExtension): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

And if I modify the behat.yml to state:

```
extensions:
Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
```

then I get:

```
 [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
 Unrecognized option "sessions" under "behat.extensions.behat_minkextension_extension"
```

What do I need to change to resolve this and get my behat tutorial project working with Browserstack? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is what is working for me(behat 2.4):

```
default:
 extensions:
   Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
    base_url: my_url
    goutte: ~
    selenium2:
     capabilities: { "capability_name": "cap_value" }
```

Please not that some of the BS capabilities might not be recognized by selenium.
Also you can take a look at this repo: [behat-mink-browserstack](https://github.com/nulpunkt/behat-mink-browserstack)